# nginx configration on azure

Tags: azure, nginx, web-config

I want to change the links to be SEO-friendly. But I couldn't run it properly so far. Please advise me on a solution to this problem. Also, I have a startup command like "`cp /home/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; service nginx restart`" on azure->  ->configration->General Settings
Here is my Nginx server block.

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
   #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    absolute_redirect off;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    #server_name  sitename.azurewebsites.net[; 

    location / {            
        index  index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above shared information, we have understood that you are trying to create custom startup by passing the commands in `startup` command under configurations in the portal.

You need to use `service nginx reload` instead of `service nginx restart` as mentioned in [this sample documentation](https://azureossd.github.io/2021/09/02/php-8-rewrite-rule/index.html) on how to change the rewrite rule in PHP 8 azure webapps.

For [custom startup script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-python-web-app-on-app-service#create-a-startup-file) it is always recommended to create file under `/home` named startup.txt, startup.sh, or another name of your choice that contains your startup command(s) and pass the path of the file to the startup command under configuration in the portal.

Comment: Dear VenkateshDodda, I read the article and checked the documents so these solved my problem.

Comment: @Bos - Glad to know that your problem has resolved :)